# Writing citation in beamer

Tags: beamer

```
\documentclass[8pts]{beamer} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsrefs}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphics,graphicx}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage{tkz-berge}
\usepackage{pgf, tikz}
%\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\setbeamerfont{description}{size=\small}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.4}
\def\B(G){\mathcal{T}_{\mathcal{B}_G}}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, automata}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
%\usecolortheme{default}
\useoutertheme{miniframes}
%\usefonttheme{serif}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
%\mathcolor{blue}
\mode<presentation>
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\begin{document}


\begin{frame}\begin{block}{Main objective}\begin{footnotesize}
%\begin{itemize}
\vspace{.5mm}
 \justifying{Godsil \footnote{C.D. Godsil,
Inverses of trees,
{\em Combinatorica}, 5 (1985) 33-39.} posed the problem of characterizing the bipartite graphs with a unique perfect matching which possesses an inverse. Akbari and Kirkland \footnote{S. Akbari, S.J. Kirkland, On unimodular graphs,
{\em Linear Algebra and its Applications}, 421 (2007) 3-15.
} characterized the bipartite, unicyclic graphs with a unique perfect matching possessing an inverse. Among all such invertible bipartite, unicyclic graphs with
unique perfect matching, Tifenbach and Kirkland \footnote{
R. M. Tifenbach, S. J. Kirkland, Directed intervals and the dual of a graph,
{\em Linear Algebra and its Applications}, 431 (2009), 792-807.
} identified those that have self inverse.}

%\end{itemize}
\end{footnotesize}

\end{block}
\footnote{C.D. Godsil,
Inverses of trees,
{\em Combinatorica}, 5 (1985) 33-39.}

 \footnote{S. Akbari, S.J. Kirkland, On unimodular graphs,
{\em Linear Algebra and its Applications}, 421 (2007) 3-15.
} 

\footnote{
R. M. Tifenbach, S. J. Kirkland, Directed intervals and the dual of a graph,
{\em Linear Algebra and its Applications}, 431 (2009), 792-807.
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I am trying to write the citation as a footnote in beamer. But it does not fit in the frame. How I can write it? Please give some idea.

Comment: Could you please clarify the desired output? Do you want to replace the footnotes inside of the colored block by footnotes a the bottom of the slide?

Comment: I want to put the footnotes at the bottom of the slide

Answer (score 1):

With the `\footnotemark`/`\footnotetext` approach you can achieve the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass[8pts]{beamer} 
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.4}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\useoutertheme{miniframes}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\mode<presentation>
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]

\setbeamertemplate{sidebar right}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{\hfill\usebeamertemplate***{navigation symbols}}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{Main objective}
\footnotesize \justifying
Godsil\footnotemark[1] posed the problem of characterizing the bipartite graphs with a unique perfect matching which possesses an inverse. Akbari and Kirkland\footnotemark[2] characterized the bipartite, unicyclic graphs with a unique perfect matching possessing an inverse. Among all such invertible bipartite, unicyclic graphs with
unique perfect matching, Tifenbach and Kirkland\footnotemark[3] identified those that have self inverse.
\end{block}

\footnotetext[1]{C.D. Godsil,
Inverses of trees,
{\em Combinatorica}, 5 (1985) 33-39.}
 \footnotetext[2]{S. Akbari, S.J. Kirkland, On unimodular graphs,
{\em Linear Algebra and its Applications}, 421 (2007) 3-15.
} 
\footnotetext[3]{
R. M. Tifenbach, S. J. Kirkland, Directed intervals and the dual of a graph,
{\em Linear Algebra and its Applications}, 431 (2009), 792-807.
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: ok. It is fine. But the slide numbers are missing. Is it possible to give the slide numbers also in each slide?

Comment: @J.Doe: Do you also want to keep the navigation symbols?

Comment: yeah. I want to keep those symbols also

Comment: yeah. I want to keep those symbols together with slide numbers